# A function to return 1 if and only if two strings match in a certain number of characters

Tags: functions, mathematical-modeling

I want to formulate equation for comparing two strings $A$, and $B$ each of length $x$. The function should be $1$ if they are matching in at least $x-l$ characters. Otherwise the function should be $0$.

$$
\text{match}(A,B,x,l) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{????} \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

I want to figure out the condition as shown in the formula above.

Comment: excuse me but I am new, so I am not sure which tag should I use.

Comment: As for the content, try $\min(1,\max(0, L+1 - \sum |a_i-b_i|))$ if those are binary strings. Actually, I don't know if they are -- can you clarify what alphabet is used here?

Comment: This is DNA string, so basically each letter can have 4 different values

Comment: Then replace $|a_i-b_i|$ by $\delta(a_i,b_i)$, where $\delta(u,v)$ is a function of two variables which returns $1$ iff they are distinct. It's still not clear what you are really looking for, though. A function that processes letters is usually called an "algorithm", coded in some language.

Comment: I think you are right, I will write a pseudo code instead of going that deep in mathematical model

Answer (score 0):

You could try some recursive definition:

\begin{align}
\text{cmatch}(\epsilon, \epsilon, 0, l) &= 0 \\
\text{cmatch}(u, v, x, l) &= 0 \quad (l < 0) \\
\text{cmatch}(u, v, x, l) &= 0 \quad (l \ge x ) \\
\text{cmatch}(au, av, x, l) &= 1 + \text{cmatch}(u, v, x - 1, l - 1) \\
\text{cmatch}(au, cv, x, l) &= 0 + \text{cmatch}(u, v, x - 1, l) \\
\text{cmatch}(au, gv, x, l) &= 0 + \text{cmatch}(u, v, x - 1, l) \\
\text{cmatch}(au, tv, x, l) &= 0 + \text{cmatch}(u, v, x - 1, l) \\
\text{cmatch}(cu, av, x, l) &= 0 + \text{cmatch}(u, v, x - 1, l) \\
& \vdots \\
\text{cmatch}(tu, tv, x, l) &= 1 + \text{cmatch}(u, v, x - 1, l - 1) \\
\text{match}(u, v, x, l) &= 
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{cmatch}(u, v, x, l) \ge x - l \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}  
\end{align}